# code to invite facebook friends is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebook, social-networking

I am using this code to invite Facebook friends. Invitation dialog is opening properly, I am able to choose friends from list but still no one will get invitation. Please let me know what's wrong in this code. Thanks

```
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

Comment: "not working" is not accurate enough to be a error message, have you tried to debug it? In what context are you using the script? more information please

Comment: @Owl there is no error message...invite window open correctly,i can choose friends for invitation but no one get invitaion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn-off "sandbox mode".

Comment: Add testers to your app and try to invite them

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  FB.init({
        appId: 'APP_ID',
        cookie:true,
        status: true,
        oauth: true
    });


function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
 FB.ui({
    to: {user-ids},
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Your Message diaolog'
 });
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: it looks like for particular user..like i have   to pass individual friends id in place of {user-ids}???

Comment: but i want to invite all not individual??